# Copy or move not working with subprocess command

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to copy files from one folder to another folder. While I try the following commands from terminal, it executed just fine. But when I plugin it in the subprocess command I get no-errors, but copy simply doesn't works.

```
subprocess.call(["mkdir", "-p", "./build/subfolder/libs"]) # this works
subprocess.call(["find", "./build", "-maxdepth", "4", "-type", "f", "-name", "\"controller\"",     "-exec", "cp", "\{\}", "./build/subfolder/libs/controller.a", ";"]) # this doesn't work

subprocess.call(["mkdir", "-p", "./build/subfolder/includes"]) # this works
subprocess.call(["find", "./build", "-maxdepth", "4", "-type", "f", "-name", "\"controller.h\"", "-exec", "cp", "\{\}", "./build/subfolder/includes/", ";"]) # this doesn't work
```

In terminal what I am using is:

```
find ./build -maxdepth 4 -type f -name "controller.h" -exec cp {} ./build/subfolder/includes/ \;
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think escaping is the issue.  `"\"controller.h\""` looks for a file named literally `"controller.h"` _including_ the quotes.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for the comment. That was exactly what was causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommend to give `subprocess.call` a "custom" / "manual" list like this.

I tried with `shlex.import` and it worked well.

```
import subprocess
import shlex


subprocess.call(shlex.split("mkdir -p ./build/subfolder/libs"))
subprocess.call(shlex.split('find ./build -maxdepth 4 -type f -name "controller" -exec cp {} ./build/subfolder/libs/controller.a ;'))
subprocess.call(shlex.split("mkdir -p ./build/subfolder/includes"))
subprocess.call(shlex.split('find ./build -maxdepth 4 -type f -name "controller.h" -exec cp {} ./build/subfolder/includes/ ;'))
```

You may want to use pathlib modue to create your repositories like:

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
import shlex


subfolder = Path("build/subfolder")
libs = subfolder / "libs"
includes = subfolder / "includes"

# Creating folder
libs.mkdir(parents=True)
includes.mkdir(parents=True)

# Finding and copying
...
```